# How do you properly pass a parameter in a proc call with MySQL, Pandas and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

With Python 2.7, when I use sqlalchemy and pandas to run a proc call from MySQL, I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064,
>   u'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near \'2018-03-10\'","end_date":"\'2018-03-16\'"

```
start_date = datetime.date(2018, 3, 10)
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 3, 16)

proc_call = text('''call schema.proc_call('{"start_date"\\:":start_date","end_date"\\:":end_date","foo":"1", "foo2":2}')''')

results = pd.read_sql_query(proc_call, con=connection, params={"start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date})
```

It works when the dates are hard coded, but I need them to be parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to pass a JSON string to `proc_call`, so do just that. Create a suitable Python construct, encode as JSON, and pass it as the argument:

```
import json

start_date = datetime.date(2018, 3, 10)
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 3, 16)
arg0 = {"start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date, "foo": "1", "foo2": 2}

proc_call = text('call schema.proc_call(:arg0)')

results = pd.read_sql_query(proc_call, con=connection,
                            params={"arg0": json.dumps(arg0)})
```

The error is the result of trying to use placeholders inside a string literal. The end result is something along the lines of

```
'{"start_date":"'2018-03-10'", ...}'
```

which is the string literal `'{"start_date":"'` followed by `2018-03-10` and so on, which is not valid syntax.

---

You could also take using bound parameters a step further and [specify their type explicitly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#specifying-bound-parameter-behaviors):

```
from sqlalchemy import bindparam, JSON

start_date = datetime.date(2018, 3, 10)
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 3, 16)
arg0 = {"start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date, "foo": "1", "foo2": 2}

proc_call = text('call schema.proc_call(:arg0)')
proc_call = proc_call.bindparams(bindparam('arg0', type_=JSON))

results = pd.read_sql_query(proc_call, con=connection, params={"arg0": arg0})
```